# Why more smooth the function the more precise finite difference method?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, finite-differences

As the title, Why more smooth the function the better finite difference method?

I guess that if the function is smooth we can better approximate with Taylor series, but formally how this helps?

Thanks

Comment: Smoothness is nice, but finite difference methods are sensitive to fast changes in your function. I would say that the more crucial property is that your function does not wildly oscillate. Of course, wild oscillations can be (somewhat) mollified by making your finite difference scheme finer but you can easily run into numerical instability doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You already said it: The consistence (local truncation error) of finite difference schemes is derived using Taylor expansions. [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) shows that you can expand a function depending on how smooth it is. For smooth functions, this allows you to construct larger stencils with higher accuracy, since the higher derivatives are bounded. This is why finite differences can be used without any harm if you know in advance your solution fulfills some regularity. However, this is seldom the case for real-world problems. This led to the development of finite Element/Volume methods.